# Update C# Windows Service without Uninstalling

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services, updates

I am very new to Windows Services, but I managed to develop and install one 'polling' Windows Service.
Now, I have some updates to the service, and which is installed on lot of PCs. Should I use uninstall(old version) and install(new version) procedure to update my service ? Or should I just replace the MyService.exe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace the MyService.exe file. But make sure that the service is in stopped state before replacing it on filesystem, otherwise windows won't allow you to do that. Once replaced, you can start the service, and your new code will be effective from then onward.

Comment: Also, how can I test the service from Visual Studio. Right now, every time I install and uninstall the service to see the changes.

Comment: I tend to just build the service in Release mode, and copy-paste the exe to install location. Normally, I keep the install location different from build location. But if those are same for you, its even simpler. Just stop the service, build your project, and start the service.

Comment: I haven't tried, but maybe you could add the steps of stopping the service before build, and starting the service after build into the build process in VS.

Comment: @NisargShah Hi can you help? I made some changes to my code and then stopped my service  and rebuild it again. my exe is not being updated. The date still shows the last time I ran the code.

Comment: You need to find the updated exe and dlls and move them into the location from which the service was installed. @Unknown

Comment: @NisargShah What I have done is that I  made a new service with code changes.